# When I get a page with a cURL request, how to navigate that page if paths are relative?

Tags: php, curl

This is probably an easy question but I can't find the answer... I have a PHP script named 'send.php' which makes a cURL request to open an external web page.  It outputs the external page to the browser.  All completely by the books.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

All it does is posts some POST data to a processing script on an external site and then displays on the browser whatever that external script would display normally; ie, a confirmation message, thank you, etc.

Problem is: My 'send.php' is still the url that appears up in the navigation bar.  So if I click around on that page, and the links are using relative paths, it tries to append my current path with those relative paths, which of course leads to a 404.  Additionally, if there are more form fields on the page, and the action path is an empty string, it will try to post those submissions to send.php again on my server, which then generates errors.

How can I make it so it will still send the post data and output the result of the processing script but still allow the user to navigate the output page as they normally would?  Or if it's a multi-page form, they can continue filling out page 2 as if they were just on that site?

Thanks in advance

Update:  Solved by adding these lines to the above code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$response = str_ireplace('<head>', "<head><base href=\"$url\" />", $response);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL that curl resolves to (if you're using FOLLOWLOCATION with `curl_getinfo` and `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`.  You can prepend this URL to all relative paths.  As for how to tell whether a path is relative .. well .. if it starts with a '/' it's absolute, which actually makes it "relative" to the domain.  If it starts with a scheme, it's also absolute, and it may even lead to a different domain.

As to how to actually *find* the URLs .. you could use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` and use `DOMXPath` to find all anchor tags (or `link`s, if you like).  Think about how much money Google engineers get paid for site scraping and URL following -- this is probably not the simplest thing in the world to do optimally.

Answer (score 1):

I may be reaching here

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$url2 = "http://www.example.com";
$url3 = "https://example.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$text = curl_exec($ch);

$text = str_replace("href=\"$url","href=\"",$text);
$text = str_replace("href=\"$url2","href=\"",$text);
$text = str_replace("href=\"$url3","href=\"",$text);
$text = str_replace("href=\"","href=\"$url",$text);
echo "$text";
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution than replacing every link on the page... isn't there a way to just replace what's in the nav bar?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you want? Is it that when you click a link on the page it reopens send.php but asking for the new URL to have it load?

Comment: I would like to make it so when a link is clicked on the page it doesn't open send.php again, it just functions as if it were on that page.  But if the page uses sessions for a multi-page form i would like the user to inherit that session.

Comment: @joey I tested this example and it seams to work. I'm sure there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't just have your page post directly to the other server from the client side?  Why use cURL at all when you just want to redirect your user to the other page?

```
<form action="https://other.server.com/url" method="post">
    <!-- if the data has been previously collected and isn't being entered right now by the user... -->
    <?php foreach ($postdata as $key => $val) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= $key; ?>" value="<?= $val; ?>">
    <? } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Because I want to set the referer and user agent to things other than what they would be if the user just navigated to that page.

Comment: Gotcha. Regardless of how you accomplish that, I'm not sure it's possible for your user to inherit the session, depending on how sessions are implemented.  If the session is set in a cookie on the client end, then there's no way for you to set the appropriate cookie on the browser for a 3rd party website.  What you'd have to do instead is inject a bit of javascript code that catches all clicked links and submitted forms and passes them through to your server where you process them and grab the appropriate resource attached to the appropriate session.  i.e. a big pain in the rear.

Comment: ... the exception being if you have some influence over the code of the 3rd party website and can arrange a method for them to pass the session on to an appropriately requesting client.